# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'codiCombi' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, jsp

why I am getting this error:

Thats my code:

```
function cargaEnquesta(sessionActual, tActivitatsArray){
    //some stuff
    var objectJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tActivitatsArray[count]));
    var nameActivity= "";
    console.log("count "  + count+" " + JSON.stringify(tActivitatsArray[count]));
    if (tActivitatsArray[contador].length>1){                
        fTrobarNom(tActivitatsArray[count],"",objectJson[count].codiCombi,"","activ");
    }
    else{
      //other stuff
    }
    //other stuff
}
```

Thats the stringify result and the console output:

```
count 0 [{"mostrIdioma":"S","calendariWeb":"S","nomActiv":"Visita Museu","codiActiv":"1","tipus":"S","nomCombi":"Visita Museu + Taller A","codiCombi":"1","idioma":"0"},{"mostrIdioma":"S","calendariWeb":"S","nomActiv":"Taller A","codiActiv":"3","tipus":"S","nomCombi":"Visita Museu + Taller A","codiCombi":"1","idioma":"0"}]

count 1 [{"mostrIdioma":"S","calendariWeb":"S","nomActiv":"Visita Museu","codiActiv":"1","tipus":"S","idioma":"0"}]


count 2 [{"mostrIdioma":"S","calendariWeb":"S","nomActiv":"Visita Museu","codiActiv":"1","tipus":"S","nomCombi":"Visita Museu + Taller A","codiCombi":"1","idioma":"0"},{"mostrIdioma":"S","calendariWeb":"S","nomActiv":"Taller A","codiActiv":"3","tipus":"S","nomCombi":"Visita Museu + Taller A","codiCombi":"1","idioma":"0"}]

mainFunctions.js?v2.3:2643 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'codiCombi' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (mainFunctions.js?v2.3:2643)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:370)
```

Why I am getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'codiCombi' of undefined`
by doing `objectJson[count].codiCombi`

And why the error appears when the count is 2? As stringify shows, I got the property codiCombi.

Also I don't understand why the error doesnt appear when the count is 0.

Answer (score 1):

When `count` is equal to `2`, this is the value of your `tActivitatsArray`:

```js
[
  {"mostrIdioma":"S","calendariWeb":"S","nomActiv":"Visita Museu","codiActiv":"1","tipus":"S","nomCombi":"Visita Museu + Taller A","codiCombi":"1","idioma":"0"},
  {"mostrIdioma":"S","calendariWeb":"S","nomActiv":"Taller A","codiActiv":"3","tipus":"S","nomCombi":"Visita Museu + Taller A","codiCombi":"1","idioma":"0"}
]
```

It only has 2 elements. When you call `objectJson[count]` when `count` is 2, it returns `undefined`, as there is no "third" element (element at index 2 is the third element).

```js
objectJson[2].codiCombi;

// is equal to

undefined.codiCombi;
```